# When selecting new Type - The entity or complex type cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

**When I call this linq query I get the following error:**
*The entity or complex type 'DataModel.CustomerContact' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.*

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. Normally when I am not joining with any other tables and have no navigation properties I would typically just select cc, but in this case I need to create a new CustomerContact object so I can bind the navigation properties.

I did some research on this and is there really no way to do this? If I use an anonymous type how do I convert to to a CustomerContact since I need to ultimately return a list of CustomerContact to my application? If I simply select cc then cc.CustomerName will not get set. I am really trying to avoid creating Dtos when I should just be able to use the auto-generated EF object classes.

```
public static IEnumerable<CustomerContacts> GetList(int customerId = null)
{
  using (var context = new AppContext())
  {
    var cList = (from cc in context.CustomerContacts
                   join c in context.Customers on cc.CustomerId equals c.Id
                   where (customerId == null || cc.CustomerId == customerId)
                   select new CustomerContact
                   {
                       Id = cc.Id,
                       FirstName = cc.FirstName,
                       LastName = cc.LastName,
                       Email = cc.Email,

                       // navigation properties
                       CustomerName = c.Name
                   }).ToList();
    return objList;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the class have a default constructor?

Comment: No, I don't think so. The class is the class that EF6 generates for you when doing database first.

Answer (score 0):

> If I simply select cc then cc.CustomerName will not get set

You could do:

```
from cc in context.CustomerContacts.Include(cc => cc.CustomerName)
```

...to get the navigation property loaded automatically for you. Search for "EF navigation properties lazy loading".

Note, you need to have 'using ...some namespace I can't remember' to get that syntax to work because it uses an extension method. Otherwise you can just quote the name of the navigation property you want to load, as in:

```
from cc in context.CustomerContacts.Include("CustomerName")
```

Comment: Hmm since all of my relationships are set up for me in my database and all of navigation properties show in my model I guess I don't need to use a partial class anymore that extends the auto generated CustomerContact class and adds string CustomerName. I just assumed performance would be better loading 1 property rather than a whole object for each join